# the regular math formula for "Calculating the index value of a sequence based on a given sequence value." in PineScript

Tags: math, indexing, formula, sequence, ceil

I am getting errors on how to do this currentIndex = ceil((sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1) - 1) / 2) in Pinescript

Currently at // Update currentIndex based on sequenceValue
currentIndex := round((sqrt(float(8 * sequenceValue + 1)) - 1) / 2, round_half_up) any help would be appreciated.

The regular math formula for the expression `ceil((sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1) - 1) / 2)` is as follows:

1. Evaluate the innermost expression: `8 * sequenceValue + 1`.
2. Take the square root of the result from step 1: `sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1)`.
3. Subtract 1 from the result from step 2: `sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1) - 1`.
4. Divide the result from step 3 by 2: `(sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1) - 1) / 2`.
5. Apply the ceiling function to the result from step 4: `ceil((sqrt(8 * sequenceValue + 1) - 1) / 2)`.

In summary, the formula calculates the square root of `(8 * sequenceValue + 1)`, subtracts 1, divides by 2, and then rounds up to the nearest integer using the ceiling function.